# react bootstrap table show empty row

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {ReactDOM, Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn} from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './Check.css';
import Axios from 'axios';

  
class Check extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {isLoading:true, times:undefined};
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.debug("after mound");
        Axios({
            method : 'post',
            url : '/',
            data : {
                tag : "ALL_YAWNTIME",
                userId : 0
            }
        })
        .then(res=>{
            if(res.data.tag == "ALL_YAWNTIME_RESPONSE"){
                this.setState({times : res.data.yawnTimes, isLoading : false});
            }
        });
    }
    
    
    
    render(){
        const {isLoading, times} = this.state;
        if(isLoading){
            return <div className="Check">Loading...</div>;
        }
        console.log(times); //<----this times variable have right values at this moment at least.
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="yawnTable">
                    <h1>Yawn Table</h1>
                    <BootstrapTable data={times}>
                        <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='time'>
                            Time
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                    </BootstrapTable> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>AFK Table</h1>
                    <BootstrapTable data={times}>
                        <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='time' >
                            Time
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                    </BootstrapTable> 
                </div>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
    
  }
  
  export default Check;
```

I followed the google code but it doesn't work.
Actually, as a result of checking via console.log, the times variable contains the correct value, but for some reason the row of the table is empty.
What I don't understand is that the number of rows is exactly the same as the length of times.(times.length is 3 and table's row is 3, too. I changed times.length to test, and table's row also changed same.) 'times' is array of String like "Sat Dec 12 2020 12:22:20".
The tables that can actually be seen from the Web page are as follows.
[my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vnKM.png)

Who can solve the problem? I need help as quickly as possible. I use Google Translate, so please understand even if the grammar is different. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, for anyone with the same problem in case:

The data in the `<BootstrapTable/>` tag must have the same property as the datefield set in `<TableHeaderColumn/>`.

like this:

```
times =[{time: "time1"}, {time: time2}, {time: time3}]
```